# get intersection between two ranges in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection between two ranges (of int values) and (if exists) return an array containing the start and the end of the intersection

example

```
range 1 : 2,5
range 2 : 4,7

result : 4,5
```

I found several other topics regarding intersections between arrays but no one helped me in finding the exact intersection 
(I just found an useful function that returns a 'true' if the intersection exists but doesn't tell what the intersection is)

I'm very bad at alghoritms so i'm finding some issues and i would really appreciate an hint

Thanks

Comment: the function that returns true  if an intersection exists is a good starting point

Comment: get the min and max from the first range, and from the second range. Then you can determine the real min and max from both ranges. Everything > min and < max is an intersection

Comment: Get out a pencil and paper, and explicitly write down how you get the answer in your example.  Then convert that to code.

Comment: Successfully did it ! Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is just some basic logic.

```
struct range
     int start , end

range intersection(range a , range b)
    //get the range with the smaller starting point (min) and greater start (max)
    range min = (a.start < b.start  ? a : b)
    range max = (min == a ? b : a)

    //min ends before max starts -> no intersection
    if min.end < max.start
        return null //the ranges don't intersect

    return range(max.start , (min.end < max.end ? min.end : max.end))
```

Comment: despite the fact that its indeed a basic logic i was surprised by this way to check for intersetction (i.e comparing minend with maxstart), will come in handy, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly - you want to get the intersection of pairs

```
const range = [
       [8, 12], [17, 22]],
       [[5, 11], [14, 18], [20, 23]];
```

and you expect the intersection would be like:

```
const result = [[8, 11], [17, 18], [20, 22]]
```

It can be done with two cycles by getting the startMax and endMin, also you can reduce complecity to O(n) using indices

Okey then, now we need to build the function to find these intersections:

```js
        function intersection(user1, user2) {
            const targetUser = (user1.length >= user2.lengh ? user1 : user2);
            const restUser = (targetUser == user1 ? user2 : user1);
            const foundItersections = targetUser.map(tu=> { 
               const mwminmax = restUser.map(ru => {
                    const startMax = (tu[0]>=ru[0] ? tu[0] : ru[0])
                    const endMin =(tu[1]<=ru[1] ? tu[1] : ru[1])
                    if(startMax<endMin){
                        const retarr = [].concat(startMax,endMin)
                        return retarr;
                    }
                    else return;
                })
                const filteredmwminmax = mwminmax.filter(x=>x!==undefined)
                return filteredmwminmax; 
            })
            return foundItersections.flat();
        }
    console.log(intersection(
        [[8, 12], [17, 22]],
        [[5, 11], [14, 18], [20, 23]]
    ))
     // [[8, 11], [17, 18], [20, 22]]
    
    
    console.log(intersection(
        [[9, 15], [18, 21]],
         [[10, 14], [21, 22]]
    ))
    // [[10, 14]]
```